# How to match string and ignore the case in karate?

Tags: karate

There is a case where one value sometimes is lower case and sometimes it's upper case. this is the response coming from an API and we have to match if every field in response is correct by ignoring some values. The error text in response sometimes has one keyword in lower and some scenarios it is upper case. How we can ignore one keyword in a string to not match? I don't want to ignore whole text as it works fine if I ignore whole string but is it possible to ignore one keyword only?

```
  Scenario: string matching
    * def test =
    """

    {
  "sourceType": "Error",
  "id": "123456",
  "type": "searchuser",
  "total": 0,
  "value": [
    {
      "details": "this is the user search case",
      "source": {
        "sourceType": "Error",
        "id": "77200203043",
        "issue": [
          {
            "severity": "high",
            "code": "678",
            "message": {
              "text": "No matching User details found"
            },
            "errorCode": "ERROR401"
          }
        ]
      },
      "user": {
        "status": "active"
      }
    }
  ]
}
    """
    * match test ==
    """
    {
  "sourceType": "Error",
  "id": "#present",
  "type": "searchuser",
  "total": 0,
  "value": [
    {
      "details": "#present",
      "source": {
        "sourceType": "Error",
        "id": "#ignore",
        "issue": [
          {
            "severity": "high",
            "code": "678",
            "message": {
              "text": "No matching User details found"
            },
            "errorCode": "ERROR401"
          }
        ]
      },
      "user": {
        "status": "active"
      }
    }
  ]
}
    """
```

How to ignore the case only for user here? I tried below but it treats #ignore as a value.

```
 "text": "No matching #ignore details found"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not looking at your payload dump but providing a simple example. Use `karate.lowerCase()`:

```
* def response = { foo: 'Bar' }
* match karate.lowerCase(response) == { foo: 'bar' }
```

EDIT: you can also extract one value at a time and do a check only for that:

```
* def response = { foo: 'Bar' }
* def foo = response.foo
* match karate.lowerCase(foo) == 'bar'
```

Comment: Peter, Yes this way it works and I know we can convert to lower case. But this way all the files we have stored for comparison needs to be converted in lower case as well. The case verification is important in all other scenarios except the one keyword. So is it possible to ignore a keyword in string? Else we can ignore whole string but it's not the ideal scenario for business as they want us to compare the case but only ignore the case in this string.

Comment: @Maddy you can always extract one value and do a conversion on it, see my edit. beyond that I have no idea what the problem is. create a JSON by merging 2 or 3 files if you need. if you can simplify your question I will try to read it. else please assume what you want is not supported